# Draw conical gradient in Android

Tags: android, view, 2d, gradient

Is there a simple way to draw a conical gradient in Android or do I have to draw it my self? If not how do I draw it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
<gradient
    android:centerColor="#0000DD"
    android:centerX="0.8"
    android:endColor="#00CC00"
    android:gradientRadius="40"
    android:startColor="#EE0000"
    android:type="sweep" />
```

The example is taken from [the russian resource](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/133355/).

Comment: Here's the android doc on this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html